# How to convert PrimeNg p-calender date in date-Format in reactive form angular8?

Tags: angular, primeng

How to convert PrimeNg p-calender date in date-format in reactive form Angular 8.

Tried to use DatePipe but showing error:

> ERROR TypeError: date.getDate is not a function at Calendar.push../node_modules/primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js.Calendar.formatDate

Please suggest, how to proceed?

### InTs code

```js
const now = Date.now();
const myFormattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(now, "dd.mm.yy");
this.addSlot.controls["addSlotDate"].setValue(myFormattedDate);
```

### Html

```html
<p-calendar
   [minDate]=""
   formControlName="addSlotDate"
   [class.is-invalid]="addSlotDate.invalid && addSlotDate.touched"
   dateFormat="dd.M.yy"
   class="form-control"
   placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
   [readonlyInput]="false"
></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG's Calendar component date value has a type of Date so instead of using Date.now(), which returns a number,  you would use new Date() which returns a Date object. You don't have to format the date before setting it in the form because PrimeNg's calendar component will handle that formatting with the dateFormat property.

```js
const now = new Date();
this.addSlot.controls['addSlotDate'].setValue(now);
```

If you needed the string formatted date outside of the calendar component you could then use the DatePipe like so..

```js
const slotDate = this.addSlot.value['addSlotDate'];
const myFormattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(slotDate, 'dd.mm.yy');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `dataType` Input in your `p-calendar` component.

for your example, you should add this `dataType="dd.mm.yy"` then it will be working properly.

reference: [resolved primeng issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1384)

Comment: Probably, dataType="string" ?